# IE9 IFrame display issue - controls not rendering until refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I have a webpage that on a button click grays out the main form and pulls up a IFrame that is displayed on top. All the button click is doing is some basic javascript in order to change around a couple CSS classes in order to give us the desired result.

This is working for every browser we have tested except for IE9 (IE6-8, FF, and Chrome). 
What I am seeing is that the page is displayed but after it renders about three controls it stops; but if I refresh the IFrame then it works just as I would expect.

I have done some research and found that if you add this to the parent page it should work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I have tried these as well...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

however that did not work for me. I have change each and very page up until there to have this tag as well, no avail. I have ran it in compatibility mode from the get go as well as ran compatibility mode on just the IFrame all of which yield the same result.

I have tried disabling some our our javascript but to no avail either.

I have also compared the source from the original load and the refresh and they are identical.

i don't know what else to try so I'm fishing for some ideas.

Thanks!

edit-Updated main Q with new alternatives.

Comment: Try `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

Comment: nope, that did not help either. I once again did it spanning the entire project. I also tried    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> with the same results. I just double checked the page source and they are identical between the original load and a refresh as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up after trying object tags as well with the same result. I uninstalled IE9 and a coworker installed it instead and it worked fine for him either way. 
So I guess  my computer just really hates me. I love problems that have no real solution because they aren't problems to begin with.